# how to enable cpanel page linking for a flask app

Tags: flask, deployment, cpanel

i have created a basic skeleton of a flask app with two pages and deployed it in cpanel. in the local host it works fine but on cpanel it will bring a 500 server error if you click a menu go to a new page
[app,py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPulA.png)

[index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5bIp.png)

also on cpanel it will not load static styles on a page unless i add a forward slash to the url. any one know how to help?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking the error logs of your application so you can get some additional information about the reason for the error. Most probably, it is a missing module that's required by your Flask application. If you still find difficulties troubleshooting this error, I would definitely recommend reaching out to your hosting provider's support team to check this out for you. If they lack support, I would definitely suggest switching to a python hosting provider. There are quite a lot of managed providers that would help in such situations.